# How to send custom payload from React bf DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED to onMembersAdded event

Tags: azure, botframework, web-chat

I have been using React webchat to interact with the botframework. I need to send some custom payload to onMembersAdded event.

[Reference link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/WELCOME_MESSAGE.md)

Below is my code

```
if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
  dispatch({
    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
    payload: {
      name: 'webchat/join',
      value: {
        language: window.navigator.language,
        key: "customdata",  // custom value
      }
    }
  });
}
```

My app service logic

```
this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
    console.log('Running onMembersAdded Activity.');
    console.log(`Processing onMembersAdded Activity :: ${JSON.stringify(context.activity)}`);
    
    await context.sendActivity('Welcome to the QnA Maker sample! Ask me a question and I will try to answer it.');

    // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
    await next();
});
```

Log response

```
{
  "type": "conversationUpdate",
  "id": "Il5FyDXlgNn",
  "timestamp": "2022-03-23T12:36:21.930Z",
  "serviceUrl": "https://webchat.botframework.com/",
  "channelId": "webchat",
  "from": {
    "id": "9sdfs15-0b2a-43b1-9c7e-7d29ffa79f23"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "KywsdfkRLNGDCxjBNQQsVn-in"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "xxx_xxx@B6i2sd3Yvs4",
    "name": "xxx_xxx"
  },
  "membersAdded": [
    {
      "id": "xxx_xxx@B6i2sd3Yvs4",
      "name": "xxx_xxx"
    },
    {
      "id": "9sdfs15-0b2a-43b1-9c7e-7d29ffa79f23"
    }
  ],
  "locale": "en-US",
  "rawTimestamp": "2022-03-23T12:36:21.9302875Z",
  "callerId": "urn:botframework:azure"
}
```

Unable to see my custom payload in log response.

I could use onEvent event and check for (context.activity.name), but I'm curious to know how's its done with onMembersAdded event.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be raising because of the React JS version. As there are some glitches in handling Webchat with React V17.0.2 and it breaks the operation often. Try to downgrade the version of React to v16.8.6.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/4205

Comment: I have downgraded my react version to 16.8.6, but i still i couldn't see my custom payload under onMembersAdded event.


{
    "type": "conversationUpdate",
    "id": "H0BrGEFtaKX",
    "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/",
    "channelId": "webchat",
    "from": {
        "id": "r_1648221509"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "IMf0Zkpo4UmApoG4DZOmi5-eu"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "xxx@AYpd3DUcfUI",
        "name": "xxx"
    },
    "membersAdded": [
       .....
    ],
    "callerId": "urn:botframework:azure"
}

Comment: Better install virtual environment and try to install libraries in that environment. Execute the application in that virtual environment instead of root environment (if you are executing on root environment).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not tied to the React version or even React, at all.

Instead, it is a bit of a race condition. The `ConversationUpdate` activity occurs when the DirectLine object in your Web Chat client establishes a connection with the Azure Bot Service. The connector then issues the `ConversationUpdate` activity to the bot that, essentially, says 'Hey, I'm seeing some activity here. This "member" just joined.' This activity is automatic and cannot be affected by either the bot or the client (i.e. Web Chat).

Here's the problem: When you dispatch an event, message, etc., during `DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED`, it can collide with the `ConversationUpdate` that also occurs. The result is the `ConversationUpdate` wins and the Web Chat activity is 'lost'.

Not to fear...there are two possible ways to overcome this.

One, wrap the Web Chat dispatch action in a `setTimeout()` with a delay of 100-200 ms.

Two, dispatch the action on `DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT` instead of `DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED`.

In my testing, either of these options solves the problem and *should* solve it for you, as well.

Hope of help!

Comment: Hi Steven,
I tried both of the suggested ways. It doesn't worked for me.
[react code](https://i.imgur.com/dRmJFFV.png)
onMembersAdded code
`
this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            console.log('=====MEMBERS ADDED=========');
            console.log(`Members added : ${JSON.stringify(context.activity, null, 4)}`);
`
[log message](https://i.imgur.com/epMVo9D.png)

Im not able to see the key field which i pass in payload.